Have Https on nextJS localNetwork while self hosted
currently I have a nextJS project that I want to host with the production environment with Https on my LAN is there any way to achieve this?

Yes, it is possible. But your question is very broad, which either indicates that you did no research at all or that you failed to highlight a specific topic when trying to solve your problem. Since a very common problem is to get the appropriate certificate (since enabling https itself is well documented) I closed it as a duplicate to such questions.
